# pandas how to find one-to-one related values?

Tags: python, pandas

I have `df` of pairs of ids and I try to filter those pairs, that have unique one-to-one relations, so that no `left_id` value has more than one corresponding value from `right_id`, and at the same time, respectively,  no `right_id` value had more than one corresponding value from the `left_id`.

That simple, but I got stuck...

Let's generate some sample data for illustration:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(0,1000,(1000000,2)),
                  index = np.arange(1000000), 
                  columns = ['left_id', 'right_id'])
```

like that:

```
  left_id right_id
0  684   559
1  629   192
2  835   763
3  707   359
4  9     723
```

dropping duplicates:

one way:

```
len(df.drop_duplicates('left_id', keep=False).drop_duplicates('right_id', keep=False))
```

637

other way:

```
len(df.drop_duplicates('right_id', keep=False).drop_duplicates('left_id', keep=False))
```

633

so the results of the identical operations are not consistent, so I suppose the approach is wrong.

How to make it right?

Comment: Can you sort the two columns (ascending or descending) because then it is easier i think ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit : Clarity

I can reliably recreate this "problem", I had a hunch there is some overlapping going on :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"left" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 9, 0, 1],                                                        
                   "right": [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 15, 17, 10, 20]})
```

As such :

```
 df.drop_duplicates("right", keep=False).drop_duplicates("left",keep=False)

    left  right
1     2     12
2     3     13
3     4     14
7     9     17
8     0     10
```

and

```
df.drop_duplicates("left", keep=False).drop_duplicates("right",keep=False)

    left  right
1     2     12
2     3     13
3     4     14
4     5     15
7     9     17
8     0     10
```

In short, if any removal in one column makes a previously duplicated value, in the other column, unique ; the output won't be symmetric.

If you try with the following, duplicates but no overlaps :

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"left" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5],
                    "right": [10, 10, 20 ,30, 40, 50]})
```

You'll see that the output is the same, you should rather have the duplicates separated and concatenate them back, this will ensure that every truly unique value is kept and you get to decide which ones to throw away :

```
left = df["left"].drop_duplicates(keep=False)
right  = df["right"].drop_duplicates(keep=False)

one_to_one = pd.concat((left, right), axis=1)

one_to_one = one_to_one.dropna()
```

This behavior should be what you're expecting, just beware of `NaN` casting the `float` type to the colums.